# data binding Angular 2 [object object] not show on view

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a problem displaying the data on my View can't display objects iterated on my array. on my console show all objects with no error but I can't display using ngFor

posts.coomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';


import {PostService} from '../posts.service';
import {Post} from '../posts';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-posts',
  templateUrl: './form-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-posts.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
 })
 export class FormPostsComponent implements OnInit {
 submitted = false;
 posts: Post[] = [];


 constructor(
 private _pService: PostService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllPost();
  }



  getAllPost() {
   this._pService.getAll().subscribe(
    posts => {
    this.posts = posts  ;
    console.log(this.posts);
    }
  );
  }

  onSave() {
  this.submitted = true;
 }


 }
```

posts.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
 base: string = 'http://localhost:3000/posts';
 constructor(
    private _http: Http,
 ) {}

 getAll() {
    return this._http.get(this.base)
    .map((response => response.json()));
   }
 }
```

[console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aena7.png)
this on my view

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts">{{post.categoria}}</li>
```

Comment: You forgot to use pipe?

Comment: @Sasxa `posts` it's an array not an object

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not using the pipe I forgot moved. before ask the question :(

Answer (score 3):

Typo!

Instead of the plural `{{posts.categoria}}` use the singular `{{post.categoria}}` in your `<li>`

Comment: thanks but not working just showing a empty <li>  bullets from the <ul> :(

Comment: Try just setting `this.JSON` equal to `window.JSON` in the controller (`JSON = JSON`) then you can do `{{JSON.stringify(post)}}` in the `<li>` to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

after  doing this
    console.log(this.posts);

what was your response on chrome and i will want you to change this line
  posts: Post[] = [];
to this
  public posts: any = [];
in the posts.coomponent.ts